# Running multiple virtual hosts behind stunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, certificate, https, stunnel

I am currently running a setup designed to let me ssh into my server through firewalls, using stunnel and port 443, while also running a webserver from that same machine. This is demonstrated in the flowchart.

[image: A flowchart of my current setup]

SSH works fine, but my problem is related to running multiple virtual hosts on nginx, with multiple domains. When setting up stunnel, I just used the certificate from one of my domains. So, when accessing that domain's website, everything works fine. However, when accessing any other domain, the browser (rightly) gives an error that the certificate and domain name do not match. To solve this, I was thinking that I could either give stunnel multiple certificates (like having multiple virtual hosts on stunnel), or I could somehow get the HTTPS traffic to bypass stunnel and get terminated by nginx so I can use nginx's virtual host ability. (May be impossible to pull off). I would also not be adverse to drastically restructuring my setup if what I want is impossible with what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by using stunnel's SNI feature to serve a different certificate for different domain names, as detailed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/587618/using-multiple-ssl-certificates-with-stunnel).